# Can't step into function when debugging the source code of grep

Tags: makefile, grep, gdb, gnulib

I am attempting to learn the source code of grep by building it according to the README-hacking. However, when debugging the source code, I am unable to step into the `re_compile_pattern` function. The gdb mentions that the function links to `libc.so.6`. Is there any way to resolve this issue, such as editing the Makefile? I found the Makefile for grep to be complex and I am unsure how to go about it.

I am considering building the gnulib and writing my own code to call it. However, I encountered an error stating "possibly undefined macro: gl_CHECK_NEXT_HEADERS." I will attempt to resolve this issue later using WSL.

Environment: Termux (Android)
Distribution: Archlinux
Device: Honor 10

Comment: `libc` is the system's C runtime library.  It's not code in grep.  That's why you can't debug it.  Usually there are packages containing debug libraries for the C runtime library that can be installed if you want to debug them, but I've never heard of "Termux" so I have no idea how you'd go about finding those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "possibly undefined macro: gl_CHECK_NEXT_HEADERS" indicates that the `configure` file has not been correctly generated. There are two ways to get a working tarball with a correct `configure` file:

- Use the release tarball. For the GNU grep program, its origin is in https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/ .
- Use a snapshot tarball from https://gitlab.com/gnu-grep/ci-distcheck .

Then, use `./configure --help` to see the package specific configuration option. This help displays, among other options:

```
  --without-included-regex
                          don't compile regex; this is the default on systems
                          with recent-enough versions of the GNU C Library
                          (use with caution on other systems).
```

So, what you need here, is `--with-included-regex`.

Then, use the general flags for getting debuggable output. For mixed C/C++ programs, use `CFLAGS="-ggdb" CXXFLAGS="-ggdb"`. The default for both variables is `-g -O2`, which enables optimizations that makes for a suboptimal debugging experience. Since grep uses C only, `CFLAGS="-ggdb"` is sufficient.

In summary, use

```
CFLAGS="-ggdb" ./configure --with-included-regex
```

Finally, note that the source code of the GNU regular expression implementation is not well-suited for learning. It's a production-quality implementation with many optimizations. Probably only two persons in the world understand this implementation's code: Paul Eggert and the original author Isamu Hasegawa. For learning, simpler regular expression implementations are better suited, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times).

Comment: I read the book called Compilers: Principles, Techniques, & Tools, this book introduces how to crate a nfa from regular expression. There is a article telling how to generate a NFA or DFA from regular expression using Thompson's algorithm, the URL is https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html.
I want to write a toy compiler, I think it is very cool. I also want to write a template engine to generate my blog. The both two tools need a regular expression parser. So I want to know how the grep converts the regular expression to NFA and DFA.
At last, thank you again.